# flutter downloader app crashes after after download from play store

Tags: android, flutter

Everything was fine before uploading the app on the App Store after upload when I download the app, the app gets a hard crashed and when I run the app I get this error in console

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12836): Process: com.app.bimaristaan, PID: 12836
E/AndroidRuntime(12836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvlider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvlider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~SDFRjygIpeILGeeDdVLNTQ==/com.app.bimaristaan-65VGI5t_IkG0iNj3hMe_gg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~SDFRjygIpeILGeeDdVLNTQ==/com.app.bimaristaan-65VGI5t_IkG0iNj3hMe_gg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~SDFRjygIpeILGeeDdVLNTQ==/com.app.bimaristaan-65VGI5t_IkG0iNj3hMe_gg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake:

This:

```
"vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvlider"
```

Should be:

```
"vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
```

You wrote `Provlider` it should be `Provider`